# What is Move the decimal value and correct value in Java?

Tags: java

I have an amount of 12.35 like this:

```
Double x = 12.35
```

And I would like to change the amount to 35.12 like this:

```
println x >> 35.12
```

I am not able to find a solution in Java, where I could do that.

Comment: Can you give more detail as to how you get `35.12` from `12.35` == `12.350000000` == `00000012.35`  Why not `3500000000.12` or `35.00000012`?

Comment: IT is not clear what you want. So if you can be more specific and explain in more details what is not working. You want to switch the values before and after the decimal point?

Comment: I understood this right? you want to change holepart with decimal part??

Comment: Can the number be negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't a mathematical operation, so you really shouldn't try to treat it as one. Instead, treat it as a string manipulation.

Convert the number to a `String`, and split it up at the decimal point. Then recombine the string with the before and after parts swapped.

```
String[] xParts = Double.toString(x).split("[.]");
System.out.println(xParts[1] + "." + xParts[0]);
```

Comment: The only flaw I can see in this solution is if `x` can be negative or `NaN`, and I'm not sure how you would want that handled.

Comment: There would also be issues if the number is super small or super big to where it is expressed in scientific notation, but I doubt that is in your use case, and you can use `String.format("%f", x)` in that case.